# Android lollipop emulator Nexus S not running the application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-s

This is the first time,I am trying to run the application in lollipop.

It didn't shows any error.But it loads the emulator continuously.Below I am posted the relevant screenshot and coding related to my issue.

**In project->properties->Build Target:**

[image]

Then in my **Manifest:**

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**Android Sdk Manager:**

[image]

[image]

**Edit Android Virtual Device(AVD):**

[image]

**Note:** In that above screenshot,It seems I had already tried `Use GPU Host`

**Output:**

Finally My emulator always Loading.I am waiting almost 35 minutes.

[image]

**Console:**

```
[2015-01-06 09:53:17 - Steve] Android Launch!
[2015-01-06 09:53:17 - Steve] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-06 09:53:17 - Steve] Performing com.android.steve.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-01-06 09:53:17 - Steve] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Lollipops' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2015-01-06 09:53:17 - Steve] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Lollipops'
[2015-01-06 09:53:30 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2015-01-06 09:53:30 - Emulator] 
[2015-01-06 09:53:31 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 438 729
[2015-01-06 09:53:31 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2015-01-06 09:53:31 - Emulator] 
[2015-01-06 09:53:31 - Steve] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2015-01-06 09:53:31 - Steve] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

I tried restarting the Eclipse and clean the project.Then finally I tried using `Nexus 5`.Nothing worked for me yet.Anybody can give me some suggestion regarding to this.Thank you.

Comment: increase the RAM size to 512 or 1024 and check

Comment: Give Genymotion a shot, makes running apps on an emulator much less painful. http://genymotion.com

Comment: @droidkid I checked it.But it doesn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

To install Genymotion plugin for Eclipse:

In Eclipse, go to Help > Install new software and click Add. 
Fill in the fields with Genymotion name and plugins.genymotion.com/… location. 
Under Genymobile, check Genymotion and Genymotion Eclipse Tools and follow the steps indicated by Eclipse.

**Note:**
Genymotion Lollipop version works fine if system configuration is good, like 6 - 8gb of ram, high speed processor. for low configured PC it just show boot screen(Image is on the question).

Comment: I didn't know why it wasn't running in the eclipse.But finally you suggest me in chat site.Then I get it with genymotion emulator.Thank you for this answer.Genymoyion emulator seems to be good compared to AVD.